# How to add own template to new project activity listing wizard in android studio? which is displayed when user go for new project

Tags: android, android-studio

I have added own activity template to the activity list
but I need to list down this activity with new project list activities means that list which I saw when go for creating a new project.

Is there any way to register our custom activity template for display in the new project list wizard?

[image]

Added own template in the activity list is done as displayed in the following picture.

I have created own custom MVVM Empty Activity template

[image]

Comment: can you please guide me with adding own activity template to the activity list

Comment: @Rahul [here](https://medium.com/gits-apps-insight/tutorial-create-your-own-template-for-android-studio-1aaa9b4cb18) I think you will get all the details what you want.   If still, you got the problem then contact me.

Comment: @RahulGaur Your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25156167) was rejected, edits should not be used with the sole purpose of bumping a post.

Comment: @NileshPanchal have you found any solution yet?

Comment: @Sagar Nayak No still not got the solution.